# A program to sort the players marks, display their marks in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.9

```
position = []
name = []
all_marks =[]

total_players = int(input("Insert number of players: "))


for x in range(total_players):
    player_name = input("Player name: ")
    print("Player ",x+1," name:",player_name)
    position.append(int(x+1))
    name.append(player_name)

index_name = list((position[x],name[x]) for x in range(total_players))

print(index_name)



for x in range(total_players):
    print("For player ",name[x], )
    marks = input("Insert your marks: ")
    all_marks.append(marks)

marks_name = list((all_marks[x],name[x]) for x in range(total_players))

marks_name.sort(key=lambda mn: mn[0], reverse = True)

print("Ranking",marks_name)
```

When the marks are printed, it is based on the players mark, which is `mn[0]`, the marks will be sorted in its reverse order since I've stated `reverse = True`,
however, the printed sequence is either not in the desired reverse order, or is in a random order which is unexpected.
I have tried putting

> `sorted(marks_name(key=lambda mn:mn[0], reverse = True))`

However it won't work either, is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You're taking marks as a string and when you're trying to sort it, it's sorted by alphabetically. Take marks as `int`

```
marks = int(input("Insert your marks: "))
```

Comment: Gosh, careless mistake, thanks for pointing it out for me. Thank you~